# Characterizing Sobolev spaces using Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I have a pretty basic doubt regarding Sobolev Space.

Suppose $v \in H^k(\mathbb{R}^n) := \{ v \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n), D^{\alpha}(v) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \text{ for } \alpha \leq k \}$, where the derivative is taken in the distribution sense, so $v$ needn't be differentiable. Then how can we conclude using Plancherel that $||D^\alpha v||_{L^2} = || \zeta^\alpha \hat{v}||_{L^2}$?

I am aware that **for $C^k \cap L^2$ functions** we have $\widehat{D^\alpha v} = (2 \pi i \zeta)^\alpha \hat{v}$, and using Plancherel then we have $||\hat{v}||_{L^2} = ||v||_{L^2}$ since the Fourier transformation is an isometry on $L^2$, but my confusion stems from the fact that $v$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Comment: It has been a while since I have done much of this, but maybe an approximation argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v\in H^k$ and let $v_n = \phi_n*v$ where $\phi_t(x)=t^{-n}\phi(x/t)$ is a $C^\infty_c$ mollifier with $\int \phi=\int \phi_t = 1$. Then it is "standard" that $v_t \in C^\infty \cap H^k$ , and $v_t \to v $ in $H^k$ as $t\to 0$, i.e. $D^\alpha v_t \to D^\alpha v$ in $L^2$ norm.

Now by what you know,
$$ \|D^\alpha v_n \|_{L^2} =  \|\zeta^\alpha \hat v_n\|_{L^2}= \|\zeta^\alpha \widehat{\phi_t}\hat v \|_{L^2}$$
Observe that $\widehat{\phi_t}(\zeta) = \hat \phi(t\zeta)\to \hat \phi(0) = 1 $ pointwise, with the dominating function
$$|\zeta^\alpha \widehat{\phi_t}\hat v |^2 \le  \|\widehat{\phi}\|^2_{L^\infty} |\zeta|^{2\alpha} |\hat v|^2 \in L^1.$$
So DCT allows us to send $t\to 0$ and obtain the result.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. Also, one related question I had is: Assuming this result, how can one generalize the definition of $H^k$ to $H^k = \{ v \in S'(\mathbb{R}^n) | \langle \zeta \rangle^k \hat{v} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \}$, since how does $\langle \zeta \rangle^k \hat{v} \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ implies $v$ should be in $L^2$ (since the previous definition needs that, and it's written the two defintions coincides when $k$ is an integer), this need not be the case, right?

Comment: @Lelouch since $1 \le \langle \zeta \rangle^{k} $, $$ \int |v|^2 =  \int |\hat v|^2 \le \int  \langle \zeta \rangle^{+2k} |\hat v |^2 < \infty $$

Comment: No, I meant $\int |v|^2$ doesn't make sense, right? Because $v$ is a priori a distribution?

Comment: @Lelouch sure, start from the rightmost integral which is finite by assumption. Then the pointwise bound proves $\hat v$ is in $L^2$. Then Fourier inversion gives $v\in L^2$.